# Helpful Tips for developing WAPs

Tags: standards, mobile-website, wap

I'm starting to develop WAP (websites for mobile devices) websites, however I'm finding there are such a wide range of mobile devices that stretch from the advanced iPhone to older blackberries.  Are there any helpful sites that discuss best techniques and good practices so that I'm not ignoring any of the major issues?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking through the articles [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/), [here](http://www.groundswell.fi/sim/2008/01/23/best-practices-for-making-a-mobile-optimized-website/), [and here](http://econsultancy.com/blog/3032-best-practice-tips-for-mobile-websites). If I was tackling this problem I would try to group the various mobile devices into as few unifying groups as possible. This way you could detect the device server side and provide the user with the best looking site for their device. For instance the iPhone has all that webkit stuff that other mobile phones don't render so obviously it's site would be different from on old Nokia with a browser. I think looking up best practices for each individual group of devices is the way to go.